# how to I assign a value with a macro?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I am integrating code from someone else that is written as 
`MACRO(addr) = c`
Where this did something like `*addr = c`
Due to a change in the underlying processor I need to call a `__builtin` function to handle the data differently such as
`NEW_MACRO(addr,c)` is there a way to write:

`#define MACRO(a)=c  NEW_MACRO(a,c)` ?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the opposite?

`#define  NEW_MACRO(a,c) (MACRO(a)=c)`